# I cannot access localhost and phpmyadmin in xampp after restarting for windows updates

Tags: xampp, restart

I'm using windows 10 as my os and latest Xampp for php development.It worked fine. Windows 10 asked me to restart my computer after several windows updates I received. It said I must restart my computer. When I restart my computer and try to continue with my project web browser said

> This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

I tried to connect web browser using 127.0.0.1 it doesn't work too.

I tried to ping 127.0.0.1 and it worked perfectly.

But can't connect to 127.0.0.1 using web browser.

Comment: Perhaps you need to start xampp too?

Comment: I did that... restarted several time. only thing left to do is uninstall and reinstall xampp again.. that i would love to do if i can have backup database...

Comment: Do you get any useful info from the server logs?

Comment: When you go to the xampp control panel, click start Apache, what do you get under "Ports" or what do you get in the logs?